# the following parser-script does not run on PyCharm - on Colab it only gathers 4 records

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

he following script does not run ony my local pycharm - and on colab it does not get more than only 4 records - why is this so!?   btw - probably i need to look after the requirements and probably i have to install something like the curl_cffi ?!?!

and idea would  be greatly appreciated

```
%pip install -q curl_cffi
%pip install -q fake-useragent
%pip install -q lxml

from curl_cffi import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from lxml.html import fromstring
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

ua = UserAgent()
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.safari}

# List of URLs to scrape
urls = {
    "Deutschland": "https://clutch.co/de/it-services",
    "Frankreich": "https://clutch.co/fr/it-services",
    "Vereinigtes Königreich": "https://clutch.co/uk/it-services",
    "Vereinigte Staaten": "https://clutch.co/us/it-services"
}

# Function to scrape data from a single URL
def scrape_data(url):
    page_number = 1
    data = []

    while True:
        resp = requests.get(f'{url}?page={page_number}', headers=headers, impersonate="safari15_3")
        tree = fromstring(resp.text)
        companies = tree.xpath('//ul/li[starts-with(@id, "provider")]')

        if not companies:
            break

        for company in companies:
            contact_phone = company.xpath('.//div[@class="contact-phone"]//span/text()')
            phone = contact_phone[0].strip() if contact_phone else 'Not Available'

            contact_email = company.xpath('.//div[@class="contact-email"]//a/text()')
            email = contact_email[0].strip() if contact_email else 'Not Available'

            contact_address = company.xpath('.//div[@class="contact-address"]//span/text()')
            address = contact_address[0].strip() if contact_address else 'Not Available'

            data.append({
                "name": company.xpath('./@data-title')[0].strip(),
                "location": company.xpath('.//span[@class = "locality"]')[0].text,
                "wage": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Avg. hourly rate</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
                "min_project_size": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Min. project size</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
                "employees": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Employees</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
                "description": company.xpath('.//blockquote//p')[0].text,
                "website_link": (company.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "website-link__item")]/@href') or ['Not Available'])[0],
                # Additional fields
                "services_offered": [service.text.strip() for service in company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Services</i>"]/span/a')],
                "client_reviews": [review.text.strip() for review in company.xpath('.//div[@class="rating__number"]/text()')],
                "contact_information": {
                    "phone": phone,
                    "email": email,
                    "address": address
                }
                # Add more fields as needed
            })

        page_number += 1
        sleep(20)  # Pause for 20 seconds before making the next request

    return data

# Iterate over each URL and scrape data
all_data = []
for country, url in urls.items():
    print(f"Scraping data for {country}")
    country_data = scrape_data(url)
    all_data.extend(country_data)

# Convert data to DataFrame
df = json_normalize(all_data, max_level=0)

df.head()
```

btw - probably i need to look after the requirements and probably i have to install something like the curl_cffi ?!?!